# AJAX response failure

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, dojo

When we make any AJAX request, what are the different possibilities for the response failing and how do we verify it on client-side? 
Is it purely based on "response.status"
I am using DOJO and see one place where I am getting response from the server, but response.status is "undefined" (dojo.xhrPost response)

More importantly technically speaking from the backend/server-side, do we have to explicitly do/pass something to indicate response failure on the client-side OR is that automatically handled (assume Java in the backend)?

Answer (score 0):

The whole HTTP state is based on the status of the HTTP call. The server side component should be able to send the right failure response code/HTTP Status **4xx/5xx** as expected. This is irrespective of the type of server/client side component.

However, not all the failure cases needs to throw 5xx or 4xx status. For example, you may try to add a new record, if record already exists, the server can still send **200 OK** response and give message stating - *Record already available.*

It's all with the webdeveloper's discretion :)

Comment: Thx...but could u add more details as to what needs to be done explicitly from the backend / Java side to return failure or is that automatic ?

Comment: That depends on the type of WebService they choose. On a typical REST call used with JAX-RS specification, the Java server side component should send the 'Response' object as such with status code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the network tab of your developer tools to find the request matching the XHR that failed?  It could probably tell you more.

If the status is undefined, I would guess that perhaps the XHR was aborted entirely or that there was an error even connecting, or resolving DNS, etc.

Comment: but like i said i do get some attributes with values in the response